# ssms 2016 english version

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I would like to change language for SSMS 2016 in Tools>Options>International Settings but I have only italian version (and OS version is Italian) in the dropdownlist.

The link for 'additional languages' (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=659036&clcid=0x410) lets me download VS 2015 Language pack (vs_langpack.exe) but I can't install it because I have not VS 2015.

I installed VS 2015 in english, then SSMS 2016 in english, then VS 2017 in english. It works nicely. Then i uninstalled VS 2015 but SSMS is now in italian.

I already tried to install SSMS 2016 again (SSMS-Setup-ENU).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nice answer. How?

Comment: Ehm... can you read the post again? I already did.

Comment: I read your question. I'm saying that, if you cannot download additional languages, you can uninstall Italian version of SSMS and download/install the English version. Actually I'm using the English version. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

Comment: VS 2017 and SSMS are both in english.

Comment: What `dbcc useroptions` returns?

Comment: Language is Italian but it's correct. I'd like to change only UI Language. I need english in that dropdownlist in international settings page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem right now and for what I've understood from some google-fu, additional language packs are only available for Pro and Enterprise verions.

Answer (score 0):

You should uninstall the Italian version of "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated)" using Control Panel -> Programs and Features before installing the English version of SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the International Settings in the Options window, you need to change the following file.

```
c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\tools\binn\managementstudio\ssms.pkgundef
```

find string as **"International"**, and comment out this line.(Add "//" before line)

Unfortunately, the SSMS is still used to the VS2015 Shell. So, if you want to change the interface language to other lang, you need to uninstall the VS2015 Shell(Isolated) and run of other lang SSMS setup.

this procedure same as @SlimShaggy 's comment.